# mySQL: compared values of the same column based on category of another column (no JOIN)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, data-manipulation

I want to take the difference of the values of 1 column based on *version* column (only 2 versions) of another column. the id-value pair may exist in one version but not the other and vice versa (in this case, the difference defaults to 0). It's essentially converting tables from long to wide format with the addition of calculating the difference of the value column.

I know I can use JOIN to achieve this result. But i am wondering if there are methods without JOIN

version_1 and version_2 is defined by users. and in current example, 2021 is version_1 and 2022 is version_2.

table:

```
 id    version    value    
 1     2021       200      
 2     2021       300      
 4     2021       100      
 1     2022       400      
 2     2022       400      
 3     2022       500
```

desired result:

```
id    version_1   value_v1   version_2    value_v2  difference
 1     2021       200         2022          400     200
 2     2021       300         2022          400     100   
 3     NULL       NULL        2022         500      500
 4     2021       100         NULL         NULL     -100
```

Comment: How do you know which one is version 1 and version 2?

Comment: the assignment of version 1 and version does not matter. in the example table, version 1 can also be 2022. what i want to get is the difference between versions and if there are cases some IDs only exist in one version not the other (or vice versa), difference will be 0

Comment: I don't think this is easy without a `LEFT JOIN`. You could pivot, but I'm not sure how you would get `NULL` when there's only one version.

Comment: Also, why does `id = 1` have `version_2 = 2022`? Both `id=1` rows have `version=2021`.

Comment: And shouldn't `id=4` have `version_1=2018`?

Comment: i think one left join is fine. but i do not want to use outer join to account for cases of NULL on either version (ps, has unchanged in initial table, updated regarding id = 1 and id = 4)

Comment: I wonder how would `id=3` knows that it doesn't have `version_1` then assign itself with `NULL`? Also the difference for `id=2` in the desired result seems to be incorrect; shouldn't it be `100`?

Comment: i have made updates regarding the desired outputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm . . . you seem to want conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       max(case when version = 2021 then value end) as version_1,
       coalesce(max(case when version = 2021 then value end),
                max(case when version = 2022 then value end)
               ) as value,
       max(case when version = 2022 then value end) as version_2,
       (case when min(version) = max(version) then 0
             else max(case when version = 2022 then value end) - max(case when version = 2021 then value end)
        end) as difference
from t
group by id;
```

Comment: In my comments above, I assumed that the version numbers had to be determined dynamically, not hard-coded as 2021 and 2022.

Comment: yes.. i think conditional aggregation works. but i am wondering with updated desired outputs, how will the difference take into consideration of NULL?